# What Smart Contract Code Analysis Tools Do You Use?

Tags: solidity, security

I've only recently (~6 months ago) picked up solidity as a coding language, but with the increase in hacks & importance of contract security community-wide, I feel the need to improve the current tools I use for contract analysis/auditing. Does anyone have any recommendations for what tools to use? I currently use Olympix & Slither for analysis, the former of which is a much lesser-known tool but has proven pretty good (honestly like it better than Slither).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.